# filter rows database by ownerId java spring security

Tags: java, database, spring-security

I want to filter my account records by ownerId, and display an access denied if someone tries to access a record where he is not the owner.

Is it possible in java spring security to do that?

If yes, can we apply this to a group of users, where every group see only shared records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with the Filter annotations from Spring Security. You're provided with PreFilter and PostFilter.  You can enable pre and post annotations by annotating your security configuration file.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    // your web security stuff.

}
```

Since you want to filter out by an attribute you'd use PostFilter

```
@PostFilter("filterObject.ownerId == authentication.name")
public List<Record> findAllRecords() {

    // perform query to get records.

}
```

Spring will get all the records and then proceed to filter out any records where the ownerId doesn't match the authenticated user.

You can also apply other spring expressions (hasRole, hasAuthority, isAuthenticated, etc) as well as combine expression.  For example, if you want only users with ROLE_ADMIN to access all records and if the user does not have ROLE_ADMIN to filter out by ownerId you could do the following.  (You can user 'and' or 'or' operators with expressions)

```
@PostFilter("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or filterObject.ownerId == authentication.name")
public List<Record> finAllRecords() {

    // perform query to get all records.

}
```

SPRING DOC : http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/el-access.html#filtering-using-prefilter-and-postfilter

A nice write up of these features on baeldung.com
http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-prefilter-postfilter

Comment: I'm using pageable and it seems @postFilter it is working only with collections